# C print progress bar

Tags: c

So I am now working on a KnapSack program and trying to do a progress bar. Unfortunately the progress bar does not print. I have no idea why.

I want a progress bar to appear after every 1000 iterations (so that it updates automatically). This one should appear every 1000 iterations and should output something like "------15% Complete-----".

I've included my entire program code below. The line I am having trouble with is

```
  if(i==-1)
    return(1);
  else
    return(0);
```

Comment: By `2 ^ Nitems` did you actually mean to do the bitwise XOR operation between those values ?

Comment: I meant, 2 at the power of Nitems.

Comment: Well, that's `pow (2, Nitems)` from math.h. `^` operator is bitwise XOR.

Comment: Try printing a newline, or flushing the output buffer: `printf("...\n");` or `printf("..."); fflush(stdout);`

Comment: Gives me this error " error: invalid operands to binary % (have ‘double’ and ‘int’)" if I use pow(2,Nitems)

Comment: That's because `pow()` returns a value of type `double`. You should either cast it to `int` or do it with the `<<` way proposed in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, change `2^Nitems` to `1<<Nitems`.

Then, reconsider the `if (((1<<Nitems) % 1000) == 0)` condition.

That's because no power of 2 is an integer multiple of 1000 (i.e. divisible by 1000).

Perhaps something like `if ((Nitems % 4) == 0)` would be more suitable for your needs.

BTW, looking into your question again, it doesn't seem that you are changing the value of `Nitems` anywhere within your code. In fact, you are not even initializing it, so your intentions here are not clear!